# How to port a PostgreSQl database to Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, postgresql, google-fusion-tables

i am currently doing a project as one of my university projects and it uses Google maps and right now i am using a postgresql database which is on my localhost but i want to host it some where else i couldn't find any free hosting for postgres and i don't know whether i can use Google App engine or Fusion tables to do it. i am using postgres and php to manipulate data and generate KML files. Google Maps V3 javascript API as the front end 
any suggestions ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is one of the most [requested](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13) features, but it is not yet supported in GAE, so your PHP code is useless.  In the future, hosted SQL databases seem to be part of [Google plans to provide "Enterprise features"](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/05/announcing-google-app-engine-for.html) in GAE, stay tuned because that could simplify what you need to do.

Currently, in case that:

1. your site is implemented as a Java EE or Python web appliaction
2. you are already using JPA/JDO (only in the Java EE case)
3. you are not doing JOIN statements (not supported in GAE)

Or even if your service/dao layers are already well isolated, it would be possible to host your "denormalized" database (it would not be a postgres service) and your frontend in GAE without too much effort.